# How to combine data from multiple rows into a single row based on numbers and certain texts in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, count, average, flatten, google-query-language

I am creating a journal for trading purposes. In trading, Let's say I bought +1 Share of Disney at $1 and Sold -1 Share of Disney at $2. Now this trade will be shown in two different rows, one row represents that 1 share of Disney has been bought at $1 and the next row shows the trade exit means -1 Share of Disney at $2, now I want to combine the data from the Trade entry row and the Trade exit row in a single row so that it shows both the entry price and exit price with their respective times in a single row.

I need the desired row to show entry time, entry price and exit time and exit price from different rows. Also, the time and the price need to be averaged in case of multiple entries or exits.

This is a bit complex for me,
I'd be grateful if you guys could help.

1st table is the raw data

[image]

2nd table is the desired output.

[image]

Comment: @player0 Could you please help me out?

Comment: Should be a query pretty much, although it won't let you take the average of a date without a workaround.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: what if you sell 2nd crm share 1 day apart - still wanna only time average or time average accounting for days? what if you buy upst share twice one day apart - should that be averaged? what if after you sell all CRM you buy again some crm - how should the average behave?

Comment: @player0 Here's a sample of my sheet with desired output and with all the answers to your question. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQ6fuCuz9_e4w1yWLmhr9rX3rbZHrRbqSbqmzHy7z_n-hRKFUSgfMFOcD8QHjZKZ9jnD9M_IM1XNQ1e/pubhtml

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oNhfs_wcQVtrdjdxTt4kFAY2IBhj2cbJPrEg4IMbQys/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @player0 Did you figure it out?

Comment: working on it in my spare time... approx. how many rows have your real dataset?

Comment: @player0 Real dataset has a lot of rows, more than 200 I guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, let's do some fixing... in the data sample, you provided there is an error in cell A11 where the year reads `222` instead of `2022`

[image]

---

next... in theory, the following formula could work but it's not recommended to use it because the larger the dataset is, the performance wise it will have a toll on your spreadsheet. that said, for the data sample you provided it works:

```
={"Date","Entry Time","Exit Time","Company","Entry Price","Exit Price","Size";
 ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY({A2:E, IFERROR(1*(IFERROR(ROW(A2:A)/0)&MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))>=ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))*(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))),   INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), 0)), ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))^0))), 
 (IFERROR(1*(IFERROR(ROW(A2:A)/0)&MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))>=ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))*(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))),   INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), 0)), ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))^0)))>0)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), 
 IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-"))*COUNTIFS(A2:A&C2:C&(IFERROR(1*(IFERROR(ROW(A2:A)/0)&MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))>=ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))*(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))),   INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), 0)), ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))^0)))>0)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), A2:A&C2:C&(IFERROR(1*(IFERROR(ROW(A2:A)/0)&MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))>=ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))*(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))),   INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), 0)), ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))^0)))>0)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), ROW(X2:X), "<="&ROW(X2:X)), {B2:B, E2:E}, ),  
 (IFERROR(1*(IFERROR(ROW(A2:A)/0)&MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))>=ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))*(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))),   INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), 0)), ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))^0)))<1)*REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-"), 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")*COUNTIFS(A2:A&C2:C&(IFERROR(1*(IFERROR(ROW(A2:A)/0)&MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))>=ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))*(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))),   INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), 0)), ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))^0)))<1)*REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-"), A2:A&C2:C&(IFERROR(1*(IFERROR(ROW(A2:A)/0)&MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))>=ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))*(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))),   INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), 0)), ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))^0)))<1)*REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-"), ROW(X2:X), "<="&ROW(X2:X)), {B2:B, E2:E}, ), 
 A2:A&C2:C&VLOOKUP(ROW(X2:X), IF(
 IF(A2:A="",,IF(VLOOKUP(C2:C&"×"&COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, ROW(X2:X), "<="&ROW(X2:X))-1, 
 {SPLIT(UNIQUE(C2:C)&"×0♦0", "♦"); C2:C&"×"&COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, ROW(X2:X),"<="&ROW(X2:X)), IFERROR(1*(IFERROR(ROW(A2:A)/0)&MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))>=ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))*(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))),   INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), 0)), ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))^0)))}, 2, )<>0,,
 IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), COUNTIFS(C2:C&(IFERROR(1*(IFERROR(ROW(A2:A)/0)&MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))>=ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))*(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))),   INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), 0)), ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))^0)))>0)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), C2:C&(IFERROR(1*(IFERROR(ROW(A2:A)/0)&MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))>=ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))*(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))),   INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), 0)), ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))^0)))>0)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), ROW(X2:X), "<="&ROW(X2:X)), )))<>"", {ROW(X2:X), 
 IF(A2:A="",,IF(VLOOKUP(C2:C&"×"&COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, ROW(X2:X), "<="&ROW(X2:X))-1, 
 {SPLIT(UNIQUE(C2:C)&"×0♦0", "♦"); C2:C&"×"&COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, ROW(X2:X), "<="&ROW(X2:X)), (IFERROR(1*(IFERROR(ROW(A2:A)/0)&MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))>=ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))*(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))),   INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), 0)), ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))^0)))>0)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-"))}, 2, )<>0,,
 IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), COUNTIFS(C2:C&(IFERROR(1*(IFERROR(ROW(A2:A)/0)&MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))>=ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))*(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))),   INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), 0)), ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))^0)))>0)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), C2:C&(IFERROR(1*(IFERROR(ROW(A2:A)/0)&MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TRANSPOSE(ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))>=ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))))*(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))=TRANSPOSE(  INDIRECT("C2:C"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>"")))&  INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))),   INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))), 0)), ROW(  INDIRECT("X2:X"&MAX(ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))^0)))>0)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), ROW(X2:X), "<="&ROW(X2:X)), )))}), 2)}, 
 "select Col1,avg(Col8),avg(Col11),Col3,avg(Col9),avg(Col12),count(Col11) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col3,Col13"), "offset 1", ))}
```

[image]

---

instead, it is better to use one helper column (G column) and this formula:

```
={"Date","Entry Time","Exit Time","Company","Entry Price","Exit Price","Size";
 ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY({A2:E, G2:G, 
 (G2:G>0)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), 
 IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-"))*COUNTIFS(A2:A&C2:C&(G2:G>0)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), A2:A&C2:C&(G2:G>0)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), ROW(X2:X), "<="&ROW(X2:X)), {B2:B, E2:E}, ),  
 (G2:G<1)*REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-"), 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")*COUNTIFS(A2:A&C2:C&(G2:G<1)*REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-"), A2:A&C2:C&(G2:G<1)*REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-"), ROW(X2:X), "<="&ROW(X2:X)), {B2:B, E2:E}, ), 
 A2:A&C2:C&VLOOKUP(ROW(X2:X), IF(
 IF(A2:A="",,IF(VLOOKUP(C2:C&"×"&COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, ROW(X2:X), "<="&ROW(X2:X))-1, 
 {SPLIT(UNIQUE(C2:C)&"×0♦0", "♦"); C2:C&"×"&COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, ROW(X2:X),"<="&ROW(X2:X)), G2:G}, 2, )<>0,,
 IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), COUNTIFS(C2:C&(G2:G>0)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), C2:C&(G2:G>0)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), ROW(X2:X), "<="&ROW(X2:X)), )))<>"", {ROW(X2:X), 
 IF(A2:A="",,IF(VLOOKUP(C2:C&"×"&COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, ROW(X2:X), "<="&ROW(X2:X))-1, 
 {SPLIT(UNIQUE(C2:C)&"×0♦0", "♦"); C2:C&"×"&COUNTIFS(C2:C, C2:C, ROW(X2:X), "<="&ROW(X2:X)), (G2:G>0)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-"))}, 2, )<>0,,
 IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), COUNTIFS(C2:C&(G2:G>0)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), C2:C&(G2:G>0)*NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(D2:D), "-")), ROW(X2:X), "<="&ROW(X2:X)), )))}), 2)}, 
 "select Col1,avg(Col8),avg(Col11),Col3,avg(Col9),avg(Col12),count(Col11) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col3,Col13"), "offset 1", ))}
```

[image]

---

it took a while for its resetting grouping functionality (column N - with which [Erik Tyler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13903283) helped me with it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72354089/5632629)) but in its simplicity, it's a mediocre solution if you have a right input:

```
=QUERY(A2:N, "select A,avg(I),avg(L),C,avg(J),avg(M),count(L) 
              where A is not null 
              group by A,C,N")
```

[image]

---

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1niu9ER5YPc77Z7danN4loChTVmcmtFOmWyQBg66DRww/copy)

Comment: Thanks so so so much for doing all this! This genuinely means a lot to me. This was my first question on stack overflow! I spent days trying to make this work, thank you so much sir for putting in so much effort. This genuinely means a lot! Internet is actually a blessing. I'm a beginner trader and at this point of my life, I can't afford a journaling software so decided to make my own using sheets. Your help has been invaluable! It feels morally wrong to get this much done without paying nothing, but I assure you, I will be paying for your service very soon. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've been testing these formulas since morning but its showing #Value! in 3 cells. Everything is working good except these 3 cells. Could you please take a look? 
(Last tab - sheet14)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vkftz6sPuWcbycnWaKTHDQ6gvzviFdVgAIu1-80eGQc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I did test each column individually and found out that the issue is with the Column M and column J. They are cusinh #value error

Comment: @AaryyanVivek some of your numbers are formated as plain text instead of numeric values. to fix it try in I2 and L2 add multiplication like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVdad.png

Comment: Thanks so much, it solved 1/3 #value! errors. P2 and X2 still showing array lateral is missing. 
Here's the updated sheet. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G8l-XkfUbHSXzUDp85Nk1W8S058_1DSr5mNPXpd7VZY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @AaryyanVivek you need you add *1 there too. see your sheet now

Comment: Is there a way to sort this according to date and time both, its already sorted according to date but time is pretty random.  (TAB - player 0, #Cell AF2)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EjDrLrR4Ovcr2XC7N7Hxkdxs3kfNnwAsdTDPLE21cTc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @AaryyanVivek see X18

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand what you need but can't you just use `=average(C10:C11)`. If this is what you meant then you can use the same formula for all of the averages you need.

Here's an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-koCscNdEBUoBo4fcB9BoDy0RrfY3r4NpZwHoFSLpN8/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thanks, but the answer requires more than just averaging two cells.

Answer (score 0):

After review and using a query/pivot, I have to following output:

I had to prepare the source data

- by formatting the time to a number
- and also the position to a number
- by adding a column to identify some sort of OrderID, to link buy and sell activities to each other, so it can be used for grouping in the pivot. The way I did it, isn't totally correct as when you buy extra before you sell all, there would be an issue.
- Also I added a column to identity whether it's a buy or sell to use as a pivot source. It probably can be done within the query as well.

Also an extra thing to take in mind is when you sell more then 1 in one time, this should probably weight more in the averages. So there should actually be a weighted average be calculated, instead of just the average.

This is [my sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WB9A_XxFAxMXQUr_ghZuMMz0lGE-d4iaKpfyYnd-5sk)

This is the query

```
=query(DATA!A2:G, "select F, A, C, avg(B), avg(E), max(D)
  where A is not null
  group by F, A, C
  pivot G
  order by A
  label F 'OrderID',
        A 'Date',
        C 'Company',
        avg(B) 'Time',
        avg(E) 'Price',
        max(D)  'Size'
  format avg(B) 'HH:MM:SS'
")
```

---

initial answer:
To calculate the average exit time per day use :

```
=average(query(A2:E6,"Select A where year(A) = "&year(A11)&" and month(A) = "&month(A11)-1&" and day(A) = "&day(A11)&" and C starts with '-' and B matches '"&D11&"'"))
```

To calculate the average exit price per day use :

```
=average(query(A2:E6,"Select D where year(A) = "&year(A11)&" and month(A) = "&month(A11)-1&" and day(A) = "&day(A11)&" and C starts with '-' and B matches '"&D11&"'"))
```

where 'A11' is the reference to your summary date and 'D11' is your reference to the company/stock name

Comment: Thanks, but the question I have requires a lot more.

Comment: F13, F14, F15, F16 needs to have same ID

Comment: Correct, unless this cross reference would be available in the source data, it's currently my best approach to somehow identify this by a formula. Room for improvement..