# how to sequence a set with reseting condition only if previous state got terminated

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sequence, array-formulas

given the specific set of columns, I'm looking for a way to turn red cells into blank cells either within the `COUNTIF` process or afterward.

formula I use to get (partially) correct answer is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(B2:B), "\-")), 
 COUNTIFS(A2:A&D2:D, A2:A&D2:D, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)), )))
```

[image]

here is a copy of my sheet: **[- CC -](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GAb2GNBIWwocjAQ9eX0jiQRq3uRsF15ukeaoJVN6VP0/copy)**

- consider yellow cells as RESET/TERMINATION for ID
- after each reset, ID gets upgraded (E column)
- E column is just a helper for better visualization - it's not part of the dataset
- A column is unsorted and it may be even ungrouped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I make a copy of your sheet (the only option provided), the negative numbers in Col B are actually all text. So I didn't backtrack into the *best* way of doing this from the original data in Col A. Instead, I just worked with Cols A:D as you currently have them (though I suspect that you don't need the helpers) and with your original "close" formula as you wrote it.

That said, this should work to deliver your desired result as shown:

`=ArrayFormula({"DESIRED OUTPUT";IF(A2:A="",,IF(VLOOKUP(A2:A&"~"&COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A))-1,{SPLIT(UNIQUE(A2:A)&"~0|0","|");A2:A&"~"&COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A)),C2:C},2,FALSE)<>0,,IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(B2:B), "\-")), COUNTIFS(A2:A&D2:D, A2:A&D2:D, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)), )))})`

My contribution is this part:

`IF(VLOOKUP(A2:A&"~"&COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A))-1,{SPLIT(UNIQUE(A2:A)&"~0|0","|");A2:A&"~"&COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A)),C2:C},2,FALSE)<>0,, [most of your previous formula])`

In plain English, this looks up the last occurrence of each ID. Only if that last occurrence had a 0 value in Col C will the results of your main formula be shown.

I stacked `SPLIT(UNIQUE(A2:A)&"~0|0","|")` on top of the actual `ID~Row, Col C` values so that the first occurrence of any ID will still find a 0 and will not result in an error. (Adding `IFERROR` would have unnecessarily lengthened the formula.)

NOTE 1: I *assumed* here that you original "close" formula works as you expect. I did not test it under close scrutiny. I just plugged it into my extended formula that determines *where* to place results.

NOTE 2: Normally, I don't get into complex formulas on these forums, for the sheer sake of time and the fact that I stay very busy. But you help out a ton on this forum, so I was happy to invest back into your own rare inquiry here.

Comment: spot on! thank you. I played with this particular vlookup/offset idea before asking, but abandon it because it was not in conjunction with my initial IF formula so it threw undesired results. this was the last missing puzzle piece for https://stackoverflow.com/a/72355516/5632629

Comment: Be sure to test your initial formula that returns the counts. To my eye, it may have issues if data is out of order and/or multiple increases happen consecutively. I could be wrong, but at least check it. On a side note... you are very generous to help other to the extent you do. I would just caution you not to work developers (or yourself) out of a job by giving away complex, custom, time-intensive work for free too often. Value your skill set enough to decline doing too much of that kind of work for free. (You can always solve problems for your own practice without posting the solutions.)

Comment: And as my post was "spot on" here, would you mark it as "Best Answer." (Blah, blah, blah... you know the drill.) ::grin::

Comment: noted, shall double-check if it holds... yeah, thx for the advice. so far it was always like "playing in sheets coz I am bored and maybe improving my skills alongside"-kind of a thing. but lately, there are some ppl that I picked on the road who abuse my generosity to solve complex dashboards for free which takes days to complete on my level. maybe I should reconsider my worth even if it's low and amateurish.

Comment: I don't consider you "low and amateurish," and I've been at this a long time, making good money. Remember: *whatever* we do for people here is more than they can do for themselves. And when we can't do something ourselves in life, the norm is that we pay someone else to do it for us. Unfortunately, most people will abuse generosity as long as they are allowed to do so. Don't allow them to. That is 100% up to you.