# Conditionally summing a column based on the Sum result at each point

Tags: google-sheets

I'm making a Stock portfolio tracker on GSheets and I've come across the following problem:
I have a Transactions Sheet where I record what kind of transactions I have performed with Date, Ticker, amount of stocks purchased, price, action type (buy, sell, dividend, deposit, withdrawal)
And an Overview sheet with a basic table of all the stocks I have currently and the average value I have on my portfolio of each.

The way I calculate the average price is the following: I sum the amount of shares bought * price bought, divided by the total number of available shares.

The issue is the following:

- On date X, I opened a position for `NASDAQ:T` for 24$ per share
- On date Y, I closed the position for `NASDAQ:T` Sell all available stocks for 22$ per share
- Yesterday, I bought `NASDAQ:T` for 21$ per share.

For the sake of simplicity, let's say on date X I bought 1 share and yesterday I bought 1 share.

The way I calculate it now on my Overview sheet is: `=SUMIF(Transactions!B$2:B, A6, Transactions!F$2:F) / E6`, Where:

- `Transactions!B` column has the Ticker,
- A6 is the ticker in the current sheet,
- `Transactions!F` contains the total money paid in the transaction (shares * price),
- E6 is the amount of available stocks in my portfolio.

This method, brings a total of ($24 - $22 + $21) / 1 = $23 which is incorrect. How can I make this formula aware of my position close, so that everything before it is not taken into account?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72355516/5632629